# What is the meaning of -<cloptr1> in ATS?

Tags: ats

I often see a type like `(int, int) -<cloptr1> bool`. What does it really mean?
How does it compare to a type like `(int, int) -<cloref1> bool`?

Answer (score 1):

The `-<cloptr1>` part of the type involves the decorated arrow notation to signify effects for the given function.

See [this ATS Wiki page](https://github.com/githwxi/ATS-Postiats/wiki/effects) for a list of available effects; `cloptr1` means that the function is a linear closure that must be explicitly freed (and thus does not require garbage collection to be enabled, in contrast to the `cloref1`-denoted closure functions). See the [chapter on linear closures](http://ats-lang.sourceforge.net/DOCUMENT/ATS2TUTORIAL/HTML/c1220.html) from *A Tutorial on Programming Features in ATS* for the detailed description and explanation.